# Condition in ASP Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

This is my situation, I wanted to check whether my DataTable contains value for a particular column, if so i wanted display the image.

Here is my code,

```
<%if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoID") != "") 
{%>
    <img src="<%#ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURLImages"] %>VideoIcon.png" class="RelatedNewsIcon" />
<%}%>
```

It is not working, correct me where I'm wrong!

Thanks in Advance,
RaJEsh.

Comment: u can do it in server side and then bind it to repeater

Comment: how i can? i just bind the table to repeater. that's all.

Comment: u can check whether a column is present   or not in c# and then bind it

Comment: *It is not working* doesn't help anyone.. What exactly is happening? What's not working? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer,

```
<asp:Image ID="RelatedNewsIcon" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURLImages"] + "VideoIcon.png" %>' CssClass="RelatedNewsIcon" Visible='<%# Eval("VideoID").ToString() != "" %>'/>
```

This works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check it using this condition in c#

```
 if (table.Columns.Contains("columnName"))
        {

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows )
{
if(row["column"]!=null || row["column"]!="")
{
// disable or enable image as you desire
} 
 }
         }
```

and then bind it to repeater

Comment: I don't want bind the value in Repeater. I just wanted to check whether the value is avail or not. Based on it wanted to display the image.

Comment: then u can use foreach to check each row and insert it to new DataTable and then bind to repeater

Comment: kumar, understand that I dont want to bind any value to repeater. I just wanted to check whether value is there or not. based on it i will change the visibility. Thats all.

Comment: ok then disable the image tag in server side based on condition